# Moving external library from Class-based to Functional Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component, jexceljs, react-class-based-component

I'm using the JExcel javascript library with React. The documentation outlines the approach with Components, but makes use of `ReactDOM.findDOMNode()` which I believe has been deprecated.

I've tried moving it to a functional component, but whilst it does ostensibly work, there is an issue, in that the React component using the class re-renders about 5 times... and each re-render causes the JExcel element to add another sheet!

Here's the original example code:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import jexcel from "jexcel-pro";

import "./styles.css";
import "../node_modules/jexcel-pro/dist/jexcel.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.options = props.options;
  }

  componentDidMount = function() {
    this.el = jexcel(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).children[0], this.options);
  };

  addRow = function() {
    this.el.insertRow();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div />
        <br />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="Add new row"
          onClick={() => this.addRow()}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const options = {
    data: [
      [123, 412],
      [null, 32, 43],
      [null, null, 41, null, 54],
      [null, 123, null, 64, 23],
      [null, null, 41, 23, 123]
    ],
    minDimensions: [5, 5],
    freezeColumns: 2,
    allowComments: true,
    tableOverflow: true,
    tabs: false,
    allowCreateTabs: false,
    tableWidth: "100%"
  };

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App options={options} />, rootElement);
```

Here's my updated version, as a `<MyGrid />` component:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import jexcel from "jexcel-pro";

import "./styles.css";
import "../node_modules/jexcel-pro/dist/jexcel.css";

function App(props) {
  var options = {
    data: [
      [123, 412],
      [null, 32, 43],
      [null, null, 41, null, 54],
      [null, 123, null, 64, 23],
      [null, null, 41, 23, 123]
    ],
    minDimensions: [5, 5],
    freezeColumns: 2,
    allowComments: true,
    tableOverflow: true,
    tabs: false,
    allowCreateTabs: false,
    tableWidth: "100%"
  };
  return <MyGrid options={options} />;
}

function MyGrid(props) {
  const { options } = props;
  const sheetRef = useRef(null);
  const [mySheet, setMySheet] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMySheet(jexcel(sheetRef.current, options));
  }, [options]);

  function addRow() {
    mySheet.insertRow();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={sheetRef} />
      <br />
      <input type="button" value="Add new row" onClick={() => addRow()} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

The problem is that the data is coming via a fetch in a parent component. I suspect it's down to that, or possible my poor use of `useRef`. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, with help from Paul @ [JExcel](https://jexcel.net/v5) here's the trick to get it to work.

```js
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import jexcel from 'jexcel-pro'

export default function MyGrid(props) {
  const { options } = props
  const sheetRef = useRef(null)
  const [mySheet, setMySheet] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    // here's the magic...
    if (!sheetRef.current.innerHTML && options.data.length > 0) {
      setMySheet( jexcel(sheetRef.current, options))
    }
    // clean-up function
    return function removeSheet() {
      sheetRef.current.remove();
    }
  }, [options])

  function addRow() {
    mySheet.insertRow()
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={sheetRef} />
      <br />
      <input type="button" value="Add new row" onClick={() => addRow()} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

To prevent multiple calls to the external library (jexcel in this case) the trick is to check that (a) the params have been passed into the component, i.e. in this case `options.data.length > 0`, and (b) that we only call the external library the first time we have those params, i.e. `!sheetRef.current.innerHTML` - if the `sheetRef` element has no innerHTML, then it hasn't be initiated, so it must be the first time around. Therefore, the call to `setMySheet` only happens once, and only when all the properties have been passed in.

Here's a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jexcel-and-react-functional-component-8ec5y?file=/src/index.js) showing it in action.