# Using external js library in functional component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am using the CircleType.js library which allows you to curve a string of text/render it as a circle. However, I am very new to React and I'm not sure how to use the library in React. I created a functional component and used the documentation provided in the CircleType page to create... but I keep getting a 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null' error.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import CircleType from 'circletype'

function RotatingCircle() { 

    // const circleOfSkills = new CircleType(document.getElementById('rounded-text'))
    // .radius(100)
    // useEffect(() => {

    //     return () => circleOfSkills.mount()
    //   }, [circleOfSkills])

    return ( 
            <p className="circle" id="rounded-text">
                AND THE WORLD KEEPS GOING AROUND AND AROUND AND AROUND
            </p>
    )
}

export default RotatingCircle
```

I read that I might need to use refs but I'm really not sure how to use it as all examples I see use class components. Another forum I saw suggested using useEffect, but I'm clearly not using it correctly.

How do I reference DOM elements in a functional component?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving external library from Class-based to Functional Component in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61579383/moving-external-library-from-class-based-to-functional-component-in-react)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of CircleType implementation with React `useRef` hook. Avoid using `getElementById` for DOM manipulation as it is not the React way.

Sample code and CodeSandbox link:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import CircleType from "circletype";

export default function App() {
  const circleInstance = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    new CircleType(circleInstance.current).radius(100);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div ref={circleInstance}>abcdef</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-wright-lue5j?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    useEffect(() => {
   const circleOfSkills = new CircleType(document.getElementById('rounded-text'))
   .radius(100)
   return circleOfSkills.mount()
 }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the const inside useEffect like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
   const circleOfSkills = new CircleType(document.getElementById('rounded-text'))
   .radius(100)
   return () => circleOfSkills.mount()
 }, []);
```

Calling getElementById outside of useEffect will give you null error because the element is not yet rendered on the page.

Answer (score 0):

When using react I'd avoid using getElementbyID inside your components. Defining a root in your index.html and then linking it in `index.js` by

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App"; //App is your base react component

ReactDOM.render(
   <App />
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

It will save you headaches like this and others in the future. React components are like a tree and by defining only one root you are utilizing what react was built for.